# How do I enable the Twig extension?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8, Admin-Report > Status report > Twig C extension:   Not available
Enabling the Twig C extension can greatly increase rendering performance. See the installation instructions for more detail.

I installed [Twig C Extension](https://gist.github.com/kbond/1014846), but it's reported to not be enabled.

How do I install and enable the Twig extension for PHP, in Drupal 8?

Comment: From Drupal 8.2 onwards, this warning message seems to have gone away.  As per this thread https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1695 discovered below by @Clive, PHP7 performance is excellent even without the C extension.  The C extension has not been ported to PHP7 and it's not clear it will ever be.

Answer (score 2):

This should just work. Make sure to follow http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/installation.html#installing-the-c-extension and run the commands from within `/path/to/docroot/vendor/twig/twig`. Next, you should check again that `extension=twig.so` exists in your php.ini file and that Apache has been restarted/reloaded.

To confirm that the extension is being loaded, you can run `php -c /path/to/php.ini -i | grep twig`

Comment: This answer is deprecated - at least at time of writing, which is day of release of D8.0.0 - the folder structure doesn't exist, or the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Path to the vendor dir had changed since the answer was provided. Thanks to @Berdir for updating the answer http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/162813/revisions

Comment: Running `phpize` (from PHP 7.0.1) in `vendor/twig/twig` fails for me with `Cannot find config.m4.` And indeed that file is nowhere to be found. What am I missing?

Comment: This answer is not true anymore. [vendor/twig/twig](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/vendor/twig/twig)/ext doesn't exist in  the latest Drupal 8 releases.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Drupal 8 releases, the [vendor/twig/twig](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/vendor/twig/twig)/ext directory doesn't exist anymore.

To build the extension, I first globally required Twig, and then compiled the extension.

```
composer global require twig/twig:~1.0
cd ~/.composer/vendor/twig/twig/ext/twig
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Then, I edited the php.ini file to add a line about the new extension.

```
extension=twig.so
```

I ran the command on OS X 10.11. In a different OS, the directory where Composer put the packages globally required could be different.

I am using Drupal 8.0.4, but it could be that previous versions didn't have the ext/twig version already. From the other answers given here, I take that Drupal 8.0.1 already missed the necessary directory.

On OS X 10.11, I got the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/DevDesktop/php5_5/ext/twig.so' - dlopen(/Applications/DevDesktop/php5_5/ext/twig.so, 9): no suitable image found.
>   Did find: /Applications/DevDesktop/php5_5/ext/twig.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0

Following what reported in [Compiling PHP extensions on Snow Leopard with XAMPP](http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2010/11/02/compiling-php-extensions-on-snow-leopard-with-xampp/), I then tried with the following commands.

```
composer global require twig/twig:~1.0
cd ~/.composer/vendor/twig/twig/ext/twig
phpize
CFLAGS=-m32 CPPFLAGS=-m32 CCASFLAGS=-m32 ./configure
make
make install
```

After restarting Apache, the Twig extension was listed between the PHP extensions.

> [image: screenshot]

As of today (February 26, 2016), I was not able to compile the extension for PHP 7.0, since `make` fails with a warning and a fatal error.

> /Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:134:15: warning:
>         fastcall calling convention ignored on variadic function
>         [-Wignored-attributes]
>   `ZEND_API void ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_apply_with_arguments(HashTable *ht...`
>
> /Applications/DevDesktop/php7_0/include/php/Zend/zend_portability.h:231:39: note:
>         expanded from macro 'ZEND_FASTCALL'
>   `# define ZEND_FASTCALL __attribute__((fastcall))`
>
> .composer/vendor/twig/twig/ext/twig/twig.c:23:10: fatal error:
>         'ext/standard/php_smart_str.h' file not found
>   `#include "ext/standard/php_smart_str.h"`

Comment: Looks like they might not be bothering with support for php7: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1695

Comment: To clarify Clive's comment "not bothering" is perhaps more "not needed": PHP7 without the C extension is much faster than PHP5 with the extension (figures available in the thread Clive links to).

Answer (score 0):

I've just setup a Drupal 8.0.1 site

When I cd to /path/to/docroot/vendor/twig/twig and run composer require twig/twig:~1.0

It creates another vendor folder with psr and symphony in it. Like Simon South, if I run phpize in /path/to/docroot/vendor/twig/twig, it can't find config.m4.

I found that if I cd to /path/to/docroot/vendor/twig/twig/vendor and run composer require twig/twig:~1.0 again, it creates another vendor folder which contains another twig folder with the phpize config.m4 file at

/path/to/docroot/vendor/twig/twig/vendor/vendor/twig/twig/ext/twig

I also experimented with cd /path/to/docroot/vendor, and run composer require twig/twig:~1.0, and it create the needed config.m4 at path/to/docroot/vendor/vendor/twig/twig/ext/twig

Both work, but seems awful confusing for a newbie

Answer (score 0):

A Drupal 8.0.2 Step-by-Step Solution derived from ir4georgia's comment.

I have to use "sudo". ymmv.

```
cd /path/to/docroot/vendor
sudo composer require twig/twig:~1.0
```

The above command creates a "vendor" sub-directory in the "vendor" directory.

Move the "ext" subdirectory of the vendor subdirectory into the original d8 twig directory:

```
sudo mv /path/to/docroot/vendor/vendor/twig/twig/ext /path/to/docroot/vendor/twig/twig/
```

Delete the second vendor directory

```
sudo rm -r /path/to/docroot/vendor/vendor
```

cd to the ext/twig directory

```
cd /path/to/docroot/vendor/twig/twig/ext/twig
```

Run the installation commands.

```
sudo phpize
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Add extension=twig.so to php.ini

Restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: On reflection, @kiamlaluno 's  approach above makes more sense: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/192644/33367 . Also see: https://www.drupal.org/node/2618642#comment-10792098